# in R: replace values in a data frame with indices from a matching vector

Tags: r, for-loop, replace, dataframe, data.table

Sorry if this title is confusing, but I can't quite figure out how to word this question, which might be why I can't seem to find the right function.

Basically, say I have this:

```
articles <- c(237, 278, 354, 600)
ind <- seq(1, length(articles))
DF <- data.frame(x=c(237, 237, 278, 278, 278, 354, 600, 600, 600),
             y=rnorm(9))
```

I want to replace all of the values in DF$x with the corresponding *index* from the `articles` vector. As in , I would like `237` to become `1` and `278` to become `2` etc.

I have built a for loop that does it, but my real data.frame is much much larger and I feel like there must be a more efficient way to accomplish this. Here is my for loop, so that you can see the end result that I want:

```
for (i in 1:length(articles)) {
  DF[DF$x==articles[i], 1] <- ind[i]
}
```

I looked at the `replace` function, but that doesn't seem to do it. Also, in reality, this is a data.table (from the {data.table} package), not a data.frame. I can obviously convert it to a data.frame if necessary, but if there is a more efficient way to do this within the data.table package that would be awesome.

Thanks so much.
Seth

Comment: If it is a data.table, then `DF[, ind := match(x, articles)]` or the more convoluted `artDT = data.table(x = articles)[, idx := .I]; DF[artDT, idx := i.idx, on="x"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
articles <- c(237, 278, 354, 600)
DF <- data.frame(x=c(237, 237, 278, 278, 278, 354, 600, 600, 600),
         y=rnorm(9))
DF$x <- match(DF$x, articles)
```

Because in this case ind is just the value you get with match.

Comment: Actually, I changed this to the accepted answer because it's slightly faster. Both options work well though. Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
DF$x <- as.numeric(as.factor(DF$x))
DF
  x           y
1 1  0.10610802
2 1  1.71933883
3 2  0.01788855
4 2  0.83659415
5 2  0.43162867
6 3  0.68937628
7 4 -1.47557905
8 4 -0.24103146
9 4  0.14286818
```

Comment: That's great. Thanks!